# Name of Text Written in TextBoxes

Tags: c#, skype4com

So I have this small bit of code

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mood =
        var skype = new Skype();
        skype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText = mood;
    }
```

What would I make the string mood equal if I wanted the MoodText to be whatever was typed into the textBox1?

Edit: when I try `Text`, whatever I type into the textbox when running the app, it makes my skype mood `Form1` which is the name of the form.

Comment: And what is textBox1??

Comment: The first text box added to the form... @BenKnoble

Comment: Well, what is its type? `SomeObjectType textBox1` ? If you know the type, you might be able to find docs. Also, have you tried using intellisense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get textbox value by using

```
TextBox senderTextBox= (TextBox)sender; 
string mood = senderTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: Alright thanks, for some odd reason, when I do `Text` it automatically thinks I am talking about the Forms main name (which is Form1), I had to write `textBox1.Text`

Comment: @RDR : There's nothing odd with that. Simply writing `Text` refers to the form's properties as the current object you're editing is the code of a form. `Text` would be written as `Form1.Text` or more properly `this.Text`. The reason why you must type `TextBox1.Text` is because how on earth would else the compiler know which object you are referring to?? Most controls have the property `Text`, so you must specify _which_ of the controls' text you want to get. It's for the same reason you do `skype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText` instead of just `MoodText`.